# Overflow is Hidden but page scroll on key events

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, gxt

On a `BorderLayout` panel (with hidden overflow), when <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> are pressed the page is scrolled down, hiding its top. How to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i find the way to solve this problem , 
i give margin to my viewport

```
 x-viewport {margin-bottom: -16px;}
```

and Done!